# DeviceMonitor - Sending Tracking request failed

Tags: android, eclipse, macos, ddms

I am using the latest Android SDK bundle for mac (`adt-bundle-mac-x86_64-20140702`).

I am getting these errors when I try to use adb. (Launching App, Debugging etc.)

```
[2014-08-15 09:54:39 - DeviceMonitor] Sending Tracking request failed!
[2014-08-15 09:54:39 - DeviceMonitor] Adb connection Error:EOF
```

DDMS is `23.0.2.1259578`

Killing adb server and restarting makes the device (Nexus 4) appear in command line. But Eclipse is still throwing errors.

Mac Version is 10.9.4

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the solution:

I have used a software that redirects all my connections trough a Proxy. After turning off this application it works without problems.

Eclipse connects to adb via tcp over `::ffff:127.0.0.1`. Add the address to you ignore list and you are fine.

Comment: I am using Zenmate browser extension, but it is only on the browser, but I am still getting the error. :s